# SubString of a Date in Apex?

Tags: trigger, datetime

I am trying to navigate the help pages associated with this, and I simply cannot find this simple reference.  I want to show the first ten characters from a DateTime (CloseDate on Opportunity):

```
o.CloseDate.SubString(0,10)
```

I just want the "2012-11-15" reference pulled out.  What am I missing here?   :-(   Thanks for any help, all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String myDate = o.CloseDate.year() + '-' + o.CloseDate.month() + '-' + o.CloseDate.day();
```

Or:

```
String myDate = String.valueOf(o.CloseDate).SubString(0,10);
```